# How to Bind a databound TextBox with complex expression

Tags: asp.net

I have following textbox within a Gridview:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="due" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Text='<%# Bind((Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("due")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))) %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

This does not work. I get a Parser-error: A call to Bind was not well formatted. Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind.

When I use that expression without "Bind()" the textbox shows datepicker and stored date as desired, but when updating is clicked, no date is updated (because it is only ...Eval...).
What is the correct Syntax for Binding that two-way?

Comment: This cannot be done. Bind is very special construct, it only works with simple field names. Unlike Eval, which can play well with any C# around it. [Good reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements)

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I read the reference - good info! I was trying to get my idea working for hours. Originally I did not want to solve this via (VB-)code behind. May be you have an idea how to do that???

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="due" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Text='<%# Bind("due", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you. Did that before, but so the datepicker does not show the stored date, only "empty" Date i. e. "tt.mm.jjjj". I need the stored date to be shown as defaultvalue. For that reason I need the "complex" expression in my example.